# this.props.history is undefined react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Continue from './components/Continue';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Table from './components/Table';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import { BrowserRouter,Switch, Route,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


function loggedIn() {
   return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
}
class App extends Component {
   render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter  >
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path = "/" component ={Login}/>
          <Route
            exact
            path = "/continue"
            component = {() =>
              loggedIn() ? <Continue /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path = "/home"
            component={() =>
              loggedIn() ? <Table /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path = "/profile"
            component={() =>
              loggedIn() ? <Profile /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />        </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
  );
 }
 }

  export default App;
```

Then from the login form I push to the route **/continue**

```
  this.props.history.push('/continue');
```

This happens successfully.

But from **Continue** when I tried to push to **/home** same way,

```
 this.props.history.push('/home');
```

It throws an error

> TypeError: this.props.history is undefined

If I remove the **loggedIn()** make it as login route, then it works.

Need some help to figure out how to send the prop history to other components.

Comment: I think you need to wrap your exported component using HoC `withRouter`.  You can read more about it here. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Continue from './components/Continue';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Table from './components/Table';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { BrowserRouter,Switch, Route,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


function loggedIn() {
 return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {location} = this.props.location;
    return (
     <div className="App">
       <BrowserRouter  >
         <Switch>
           <Route exact path = "/" component ={Login}/>
           <Route
             exact
             location={location}
             path = "/continue"
             component = {() =>
             loggedIn() ? <Continue /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            location={location}
            path = "/home"
            component={() =>
            loggedIn() ? <Table /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
         <Route
           exact
           location={location}
           path = "/profile"
           component={() =>
           loggedIn() ? <Profile /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
         />        
       </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
   );
  }
 }
 App.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.shape({
   pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired
 };

 export default App;
```

if you don't have the prop-types package installed then use

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Comment: Add the "location" to every <Route />

Comment: Hey! Can you explain a bit. I can't figure out where to put these codes. :( I can't place  that const {location} inside the router. :)

Comment: I have edited the whole code. Please check and do let me know if you face any problem or if the above solution works. Don't hesitate to comment :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.history` works only if your component is a routed component. See your Login component. It is under the `BrowserRouter` and as the part of the `Route`. If you need to redirect to another page (component) as a single page application, you need to use `useHistory` from `react-router-dom` / `react-router`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    const LNav = (props) => {
    let history = useHistory();
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger" style={{marginBottom: "5px"}}>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav nav-right" id="app-navbar">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => history.push(props.add)}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah Data</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};
export default LNav;
```

Look at that component. That is a functional component (stateless component) and according to the hooks rules, it only works with a function component not a class component.